# New to ubuntu, scrolling can be jittery, do I need to update/install video drivers for my card?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I have two 27" monitors running 2560 X 1440.  Resolution is fine, but when I scroll any webpage in any browser, it streaks.  The update drivers in the software module didn't show anything new.  Intel graphics card btw.  Any ideas/tips?  I'm not new to ubuntu, been running it on a laptop for awhile, but recently made the switch from windows on my main PC.

Comment: What is your GPU model?  Intel iGPUs do not need any additional drivers in Ubuntu.  Since iGPUs are not dedicated GPUs, they share resources with the CPU. With recent model Intel CPUs, having two 2650x1440 displays probably shouldn't be problematic if they are just running desktop applications like a web browser.  But if you are using an older generation CPU or you have a budget-level CPU, it could have trouble especially if you are running other resource-intesive tasks. It would help to know what GPU you actually have.

Comment: Have you changed the resolutions at all? Also, would you mind adding the Ubuntu version info and a bit of output from `xrandr` assuming you are using X as your window manager. You don't need to post it all. Just the base info and the preferred and selected modes for each display? It will help with diagnosis. Thanks.

Comment: You've provided few specifics on your Ubuntu install. Whilst we're probably safe in assuming you're asking about a desktop install - it's still best if you actually tell us. We also don't know what release; and as LTS releases have two kernel stack choices; which you're using (without your release we don't even know what default that is yet).   The more specific details you provide, the more helpful we can be.  What release are you asking about?; what *driver* (kernel module) are you using?  (I'd use `sudo lshw -C video` to list-hardware of class video to show that detail)

Comment: Hey guys!  Thanks for the quick reply's.  Here is my system: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02).  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8665U CPU @ 1.90GHz  I also use a Dell docking station.

Comment: @NateT https://pastebin.com/pwBQ7kdy

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: In what state is the third monitor? Do you have it disabled in X?

Comment: @NateT It's my laptop screen, which is closed.  I only run the 2 X 27" Dell's with one port coming from the laptop and the other from the Dell docking station (WD19).

Comment: That makes sense. Does it always show as being active? The plus sign next to it (line 3 of your output) shows it still having a mode attached to it. You might try toggling the output disable / enable in `xrandr`. There is also `xrefresh` which goes without explaining. Just be sure to type `man [tool-name]` for anything that is recommended. This may feel like extra work, but if you make a habit of it, it will save you time in the end. Except for that plus sign, which I am not sure if it is correct or not, your output looks ok. Does the thunderbolt provide the power, or is it a wall wart model?

Comment: @NateT, how would I go about toggling the output in `xrandr`?  `xrefresh` didn't do anything.  Under display in settings, it only shows monitor 2 and 3 (the 27" monitors) as active and the built-in display is toggled off.

Comment: @guiverc, here is the output you asked for - https://pastebin.com/z33NtQAz